# No URLs matched- while copying file to google cloud storage

Tags: batch-file, google-cloud-storage

I am copying two files into Google Cloud Storage (GCS).  When I run the script from informatica, I get error but when I run the same script from Unix it works fine.

Below is a link from GitHub where a similar issue is discussed. I don't understand what's the issue.

------------------------PART OF SCRIPT------------------------

```
echo "$LFS_File_Path/$File_Name";

gsutil cp "$LFS_File_Path/$File_Name" $GCS_Path;

if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "copy to GCS success for LFS Data File";
else
    echo "copy to GCS Failed for LFS" >> $Log_File_Path/$Workflow_Name.txt ;
    exit 1
fi

echo "$LFS_File_Path/$Del_File_Name";

gsutil cp "$LFS_File_Path/$Del_File_Name" $GCS_Path;

if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "copy to GCS success for LFS Delete Data File";
else
    echo "copy to GCS Failed for LFS" >> $Log_File_Path/$Workflow_Name.txt ;
    exit 1
fi
```

------------------------PART OF SCRIPT------------------------

**error:-**

> CommandException: No URLs matched: `/opt/u01/app/informatica/server/infa_shared/TgtFiles/BQ_RT/DW_ORDER_HEADER_DEL.csv`

Similar topic:-

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/501

Answer (score 1):

It might be related to the permissions in that file or maybe the command is being run as a user but only root has access to read inside that folder.

Comment: Oh! I misspelled the source filename. Of course, the fact that the source is just a filename and the error says URL... it's a bit misleading (even if you know that a filename can be represented with a URL). To the minimum, gsutil should tell you which URL is failing.

Answer (score 0):

resolved it after creating another directory
its because of the hiddenfiles in that directory,the hidden file used the gstuil commands and found some escape characters init
try to create one more directory on the same filesystem and move the files from the directory

its mainly because of the escape characters,try to remove/move the hidden files
it will avoid the  the above error

errors:
1)"No URLS matched"
2)CommandException: No URLs matched

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).